# Installation of GE Plugin

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Despite repeated attempts, cold installations, removal of all Google products, re-installation, etc. the GE plugin fails to install correctly or run on my Windows 7 laptop. All I ever get (after the installation of the Plugin) is the statement indicating that I need to download and install the Plugin which, when I click on the Learn More link comes up with:

**404**. That’s an error.

The requested URL **/intl/en-GB/plugin/ was not found on this server**. That’s all we know."

I only have the **Chrome browser** installed (Version 37.0.2062.102 m)

I notice a closed earlier question suggesting the **GE Plugin does not work on Windows 7** - is that true?

The GE standalone application works fine

Help, useful suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is supporting google earth api. But Chrome some times shows error like this. I'm also faced same kind of error.so try in your internet explorer browser.It will work.